# python - How to write unicode characters to files correctly

Tags: python, unicode, codec, persian, farsi

If I run the following code:

```
text = 'سلام عزیزم! عزیزم سلام!'
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    print(text)
    out_file.write(text)
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    print(in_file.read())
```

I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
سلام عزیزم! عزیزم سلام!
  File "Z:/my files/projects/programing/python/courseAssist/gui.py", line 190, in <module>
    out_file.write(text)
  File "C:\Users\aran\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the encoding `encoding='utf-8'`:

```
text = 'سلام عزیزم! عزیزم سلام!'
with open('temp.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
    print(text)
    out_file.write(text)
with open('temp.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as in_file:
    print(in_file.read())
```